# How to modify the radius of the arc for connectors?

Tags: microsoft-visio

Visio is automatically creating jump arcs when connectors intersects each other but when those connectors are too close to each other or close to a corner it seems that there is not enough space and the jump arc is not created. I need to know if it is possible to reduce the radius of the arc and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As I am new to Visio, I exactly don't know whether it is possible to reduce the radius of the arc; however, there is a procedure of reshaping the arc in Visio drawing]. Follow the given below steps which may help you.

Click the Pencil tool [image]. Select an arc or a shape that contains an arc.

**Tip:**:   You can also select the arc or shape using the Pointer[image]  tool, and then position the pointer over the shape to automatically display the control point and move it.

Point to the arc's control point [image]. Drag the control point until the arc looks the way you want.

**Note:**   An arc has an invisible snap point in the middle of an invisible line between its two endpoints. When you drag the control point to that snap point so that the arc has no curvature, the arc becomes a line.

Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/reshape-an-arc-HP085050335.aspx